# Ubuntu create user with password in GUI

Tags: users

Chen creating a new user in the Ubuntu GUI, it only asks for the users full name, username, and account type. It does not ask for a password.

But when I try to switch to the new user it asks for a password.

How do I set the password (in the GUI), or login as the new user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the password with the GUI but it does not prompt you to do so when creating a new user.  After you create the new user click on the password box marked in the following screen shot. As you have not set a password it will actually say **Account Disabled** for you.  (Select the new user acct. on the left first)

[image]

You will be presented with the following, just enter the new password in the new password box and the repeat it in the confirm box.  The current password for a new account is blank so you don't enter anything in that box.  The final step is to click the **Change** box.  You can now log in to the new account using the new password.

[image]

The procedure is the same to change a password that is already set you just enter the current password in the correct box.

Comment: Thanks, it was saying "Account Disabled" rather than "Password" for me, so I must have skimmed over it.

Comment: @Petah Yes it would, I forgot that it said account disabled if the password was not set, I will update the answer to help others....

Comment: The issue is that the text field does not look like a text field. Design flow. It looked like just a text with not indicate that it can be edited. IMHO A better user interaction would be to ask for the password on the same prompt when adding the new user.